# How to use unit testing to test that a button launches the correct Activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, android-button

I am trying to write a unit test that will test if a button launches the correct activity when it is clicked, but I am having trouble figuring out the correct code to use. 
The testButton method does run and pass the tests, however it then causes an error:

```
[2012-02-29 16:18:08 - TroubleShootingAppTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.RuntimeException'
```

The testing then terminates early. Can anyone please advise what the correct code should be?

This is what I have:

```
package com.integral.troubleshooter.test;

import com.integral.troubleshooter.Question;
import com.integral.troubleshooter.R;
import com.integral.troubleshooter.TroubleShooterActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TroubleShooterActivityTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TroubleShooterActivity> {

private TroubleShooterActivity mActivity;
private Button mButton;
private TextView mTextView;
private ImageView mImageView;
private String resourceString;
private Activity nextActivity;

public TroubleShooterActivityTest() {      
    super("com.integral.troubleshooter.TroubleShooterActivity",        TroubleShooterActivity.class);    
}

 /*
 * Sets up the test environment before each test.
 * @see android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2#setUp()
 */
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {

    super.setUp();

    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);


    mActivity = getActivity();

    mButton = (Button)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.troubleShooter);

    mTextView =  (TextView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.title);

    mImageView = (ImageView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.IntegralLogo);

    resourceString = mActivity.getString(R.string.CustomerSupport); 
}

public void testPreconditions() {
    assertTrue(mTextView != null);
    assertTrue(mImageView != null);
}

public void testText(){
    assertEquals(resourceString,(String)mTextView.getText());
}

public void testButton(){
     mActivity.runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       mButton.performClick();
                       nextActivity =  getActivity();
                       assertEquals(nextActivity, Question.class);
                    }
                }
            );



}
}
```

Comment: Can you post more exception stack trace?

Comment: Thanks yorkw but I decided to use Robolectric to implement the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if instrumentation is not present. Running this command will give a list of present instrumentation in your project environment:

```
$ adb shell pm list instrumentation
```

I hope this help.